# Multiple commands in ruby shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of names and I need to get their unique ID's with ruby shell.

Example:

```rb
User.find_by(name: "James").id
```

Output:

```
=>  265
```

So I need to do something like:

```rb
User.find_by(name: "James").id && User.find_by(name: "Robert").id && User.find_by(name: "William").id
```

In order to get this output:

```
=> 265
=> 726
=> 24
```

What's the `&&` for Ruby shell commands??

Comment: You can separate multiple commands using the semicolon ;

Comment: `User.where(name: ['James'. 'Robert', 'William']).ids` . [ids](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ids)

Comment: Your question is unclear. There is no such thing as "Ruby shell". What are you talking about? Are you talking about the "Ruby command prompt" that some installers for Windows create? That's not a "Ruby shell", that's just a normal Windows command prompt where the `%PATH%` environment variable has been modified to include the installation directory of Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want that result:

```
=> 265
=> 726
=> 24
```

You can try something like that:

```
> ids = User.where(name:['James','Robert', 'William']).order(:name).ids 
> puts ids
265
726
24
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Simple and straightforward, worked like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`&&` is a logical/boolean "AND". The fact that these work in your example is due to how Ruby deals with truthy/falsy values – you can read the details here: https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/02/ruby-booleans/.

To hopefully answer your questions: I would go with an SQL inclusion operation somewhat like this:

```rb
relation = User.where(name: ["James", "Robert", "William"])

# If you really just are looking for the IDs, you can use this the following.
# Note that the order of the IDs isn't the same as the input parameters,
# so if you receive back 1, 5, 10, that doesn't mean that James = 1,
# Robert = 5 and William = 10. If you need a certain order, you need to
# add an `order` clause.

puts relation.ids

# If you want to do more with the result than just have its IDs, you can
# iterate over it like so:
relation.each do |user|
  puts "#{user.name}: #{user.id}"
end
```

Comment: Minor comment you are missing a right bracket (`]`) also since the OP is looking for the ids there is literally a method called `ids`

Answer (score 0):

`find_by` will always return a single result if present.

You need to use `where`.
Try the below code:

```
User.where("name like ? or name like ? or name like ?","%James%", "%Robert%", "%William").pluck(:id)
```

Comment: This will lead to an error because the way you have it, `James`, `Robert` and `William` are directly interpolated and therefore presumed to be constants (which don't exist). Moreover, it's strongly discouraged to directly interpolate values in SQL because it can lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank you, but some usernames have dots so this is the output: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
NoMethodError (undefined method `Smith' for nil:NilClass)

Comment: @ClemensKofler Thanks, I mis-typed that, my bad, updated the answer, Fran What do you mean by dots..?

Comment: @ClemensKofler SQL Injection is not possible when using the above because the first element is a template and the latter are parameters to that template.

Comment: @ClemensKofler how should work on ruby's command shell? Do I need to compile .rb program first? {ruby newbie here}